How to set up 'git push remote master' to automatically update files on production web server?
I have my website running on a remote server with gunicorn/nginx. The nginx runs from /var/www directory and its owned by root:www-data
drwxrwxr-x  5 root      www-data  4096 Apr  8 17:32 www

I also have a bare git repository in /var/gitrepo as follows
drwxrwxr-x  7 django django 4096 Apr  8 23:20 gitrepo

django user is member of sudo group but not of www-data group. There are not other users with login shells on the server.
Then I have post-receive git hook in /var/gitrepo/hooks/post-receive as follows
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www --git-dir=/var/gitrepo checkout -f

Idea is that when I run git push ssh://django@<site_IP>:/var/gitrepo masterfrom my laptop, the repo gets pushed to the gitrepo directory and then the /var/www will receive the updated files via the post-receive hook.
The above post-receive hook naturally fails, because django user doesn't have permissions to create the destination directory inside /var/www directory. One solution, I can think of, is to add django user to :www-data group. What are the security implications of that? I can also make django the owner of /var and /var/www. But that might be too many permissions for django user.
Edit: If I add the django user to www-data group then new git repo files are copied over to /var/www directory correctly and the web site works correctly. I just don't know if this can create a security issue.
What should I do?
Thanks

Why not simply create a symlink in /var/www that points to your git repo? The security implications of having this django user be a member of sudo are way more severe than any write-permissions shenanigans you can come up with.
